# `how to read a data set and remove commas from measured variables

Tags: r, read.csv

I am having an issue creating a linear model from a data frame I have stored because the independent variable contains comma-separators (i.e 314,567.5 vs 314567.4). How could I use `read.csv` or `readr` to read a data set and return a data frame without the commas in that specific column?

Comment: Use `preetyNum`  after reading the file. Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648323/how-to-separate-thousands-with-space/30648432#30648432)

Comment: What separators does your .csv file use?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the commas question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-a-csv-file-in-r-where-some-numbers-contain-commas).

However, you first need to read the file into `R`. Although it can be a bit of a pain, I've found that `read.fwf` is often the best solution in these situations, unless you have a different delimiter, such as a pipe, `|`, in which case `read.delim` would probably be best.